# How to get unique id count by month and year?

Tags: sql

I have a query that is counting the total user_id 
but I would like it to get the count for each month/year 
using the column start_date.

start_date is a collumn in agentdispodetail and datetype.

start_date is usually like:
2014-11-21 14:47:15.680

```
select distinct user_id, count(*) as total_id
  from agentdispodetail
  group by  user_id
```

I use sql 2012.

Comment: what is start_date? a column of agentdispodetail?

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id, year(start_date), month(start_date), count(*) as total_id
from agentdispodetail
group by user_id, year(start_date), month(start_date)
order by user_id, year(start_date), month(start_date)
```

Comment: I think the OP might be asking for just a count of the number of records for the month/year, in which case the user_id should be taken out. Other than that. good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You say something like

```
select year  = datepart(  year  ,start_date  ) ,
       month = datepart( month , start_date ) ,
       N     = count( distinct user_id )
from ...
where ...
group by datepart( year  , start_date ) ,
         datepart( month , start_date )
order by 1,2
```

Another technique uses a little date arithmetic:

```
select start_date = dateadd(day ,
                      1-datepart(day,start_date) ,
                      convert(date,start_date)
                      ) ,
       N          = count( distinct user_id )
from ...
where ...
group by dateadd(day, 1-datepart(day,start_date) , convert(date,start_date) )
order by 1
```

If the table schema has the column `user_id` as a unique column — it's either the primary key of the table or has a unique index on it — you can dispense with the `distinct` keyword.